# How to edit epub file content with PHP

Tags: php, edit, libraries, epub

I wanna edit epub file content in PHP to erase some text from begging of the ebook. I have tried some libraries with no success.

```
https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub
https://github.com/Vaporbook/BookGluttonEpub
https://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary
```

They can edit authors, isbn, description, creator, cover, etc., or create new epub file, or open epub file, but I haven't found some solution for editing content.

Do you know some easy way how to do it?

Comment: You could read the content, put it in a variable, edit the text and place it in a new epub, delete the old epub and voila

Comment: Yes, this crossed my mind too, but it's not so simple. Load content with one library and create new epub from scratch with other one? Every library work in different style - with / without chapter, problem with css, move metadata, etc. it's heavy and bad solution.

Comment: Fair enough, have you tried what is marked in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6525775/4461980?

Answer (score 1):

Now I know, that you can just unzip epub as simple zip file and then edit all html and css files :)

After you have done changes, just zip the files back.